# Interactive Elisp Function to Directly Search File Names with `emacs-helm-ag` (-g option)

Tags: emacs, ag, emacs-helm

I use [emacs-helm-ag](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-ag) to search file content and file names in a project. My `emacs-helm-ag` configuration is:

```
; Helm Ag mode
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/emacs-helm-ag")
(require 'helm-ag)
(custom-set-variables
    '(helm-ag-base-command "ag --nocolor --nogroup")
    '(helm-ag-command-option "--hidden --ignore *~ --ignore .git --ignore .idea"))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s s") 'helm-do-ag-project-root)
```

To search **file content** (a word in all project files) I press `M-s s` and type the word to search.

To search **file name** (a file in a list of all files of a project) I press `M-s s` then I have to type `-g` (I would like to automate this step) and then I type the file name to search.

**Question**. Please could you help me to come up with an `elisp` interactive function that directly searches for file names in a project  by automatically inserting `-g` command line option (and preferably reuses `helm-do-ag-project-root` from `emacs-helm-ag` package) and only requires the file name to be typed by the end user. I would like to have an interactive function to search file names in a project and be able to call the function with a different key binding. Something similar to:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s f") 'helm-do-ag-project-root-file-names)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a suggestion from [DasEwigeLicht on Reddit](https://redd.it/7tbupv) I've created a function which searches for file names in a project using `ag -g <pattern>` as required in my question. The function is:

```
(defun helm-do-ag-project-root-search-file-names ()
    "Searches file names in a project using ag -g <pattern> command line tool"
    (interactive)
    (let ((helm-ag-command-option (concat helm-ag-command-option " -g")))
        (helm-do-ag-project-root)))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-s f") 'helm-do-ag-project-root-search-file-names)
```

Thank you very much [DasEwigeLicht](https://www.reddit.com/user/DasEwigeLicht) for a helpful suggestion!

Comment: Is it possible to add more than one option to helm-ag-command-option? It doesn't seem to be the case.